# battery for B+ model?

Tags: pi-3b+, battery

Could one of these rechargeable battery packs work for a rasp pi B+? Klientool and BestBuy are some options I can packup locally, plus I like Klientools. Any tips greatly appreciated...

[Klientools](https://www.kleintools.com/catalog/jobsite-accessories/portable-rechargeable-battery-10050mah)

[Bestbuy option](https://www.bestbuy.com/site/anker-powercore-metro-20000-mah-portable-charger-for-most-usb-enabled-devices-dark-gray/6375636.p?skuId=6375636&ref=212&loc=1&extStoreId=43)

[I also notice a DIY battery pack option](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/pi-go-x-ways-powering-raspberry-pi-portable-projects/#diy-portable-raspberry-pi-power-supply:%7E:text=DIY%20Portable%20Raspberry%20Pi%20Power%20Supply). Curious how hard this would be to cobble together with maybe some rechargeable battery's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any power source can work with the RPi - *as long as it delivers 5 volts to the input, and it can supply enough current*. If your battery is not 5V, it can still work, but you'll need to add a **voltage regulator**.

Your run time will depend on the battery capacity rating; e.g. *amp-hours*. There are some simple [calculations in this other answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/117533/83790) to help you estimate your run time. If you can't be bothered with the details, [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/114204/83790) suggests you **might** get 1 hour of operating time from the KleinTools battery.

Comment: It also has to be USB Type-C right?

Comment: @HenryHub: No - only the RPi 4-series macines use USB-C.